# process the data of an image like pdf or something else using pdfcreator

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript, pdftotext, xpdf

hay all.
maybe you guys can  help me in my project.
im using pdfcreator as a virtual printer to print to a file some images. 
can be pdf can be any type of image. but i need to extract data from it.
can it be done? im using C#.

Comment: Please specify in more details, what kind of data you want to extract. And from which file you want to extract: from a PDF created by PDFCreator? From an image created by PDFCreator?? Or...???

Comment: i want to extract a text from the pdf or image. maybe the data sent to the printer. im looking for a number in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extract text from images.

In principle, you can extract text from PDFs.

Here are two methods using Free software commandline utilities; maybe one of them fits your needs:

1. `pdftotext.exe` (part of [**Foolabs' XPDF utilities**](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html))
2. `gswin32c.exe` (Artifex' [**Ghostscript**](http://www.ghostscript.com/releases/))

Example commandlines to extract all text from pages 3-7:

**pdftotext:**

```
pdftotext.exe ^
   -f 3 ^
   -l 7 ^
   -epl dos ^
   -layout ^
   "d:\path with spaces\to\input.pdf" ^
   "d:\path\to\output.txt"
```

You want to get the text output to stdout instead of a file? OK, try this:

```
pdftotext.exe ^
   -f 3 ^
   -l 7 ^
   -epl dos ^
   -layout ^
   "d:\path with spaces\to\input.pdf" ^
   -
```

**Ghostscript:**
(Check that your installation has `ps2ascii.ps` in its *lib* subdirectory)

```
gswin32c.exe ^
   -q ^
   -sFONTPATH=c:/windows/fonts ^
   -dNODISPLAY ^
   -dSAFER ^
   -dDELAYBIND ^
   -dWRITESYSTEMDICT ^
   -dSIMPLE ^
   -f ps2ascii.ps ^
   -dFirstPage=3 ^
   -dLastPage=7 ^
   "c:/path/to/input.pdf" ^
   -dQUIET
```

Text output will appear on stdout. If you test this in a cmd.exe window, you can redirect this to a file by appending `> /path/to/output.txt` to the command.